# how to get a string from .getId()

Tags: java, android

I have a series of buttons in my mainactivity and when i click one of them i want to display their id but using view.getId() i get an integer and converting it to string i get a string of numbers,how can i get the id that i written on the xml?

```
public void giocaCarta(View view){
    Toast.makeText(this,Integer.toString(view.getId()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
```

this is the code of the button:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_g2_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="giocaCarta"
            android:text="Button" />
```

i want to read on the toast "btn_g2_1" and not a sequence of numbers,there is some method that can provide this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String viewIdName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(myView.getId())
```

Answer (score 1):

I wondering why you need that but for getting that id Use this code

```
view.getResources().getResourceName(view.getId());
```